# Detect if record has been changed in AURA recordEditForm

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, aura

I have a recordeditform aura components used for editing case record. For standard component: When two users update same record (same field, example description) from their browsers at the same time, salesforce throws pop like below.

[image]

How I can detect and show similar kind of pop up in aura recordedit form page?